# reducing db queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

i am attempting to reduce the load our database, and have read that using the :include method can help with this.
i current have the following line of code that is allowing me to select all the information i need, but when i attempt to render this in my view with the count i am hitting the database over and over again

```
@sports = Sport.includes([:teams]).all
```

in my view im doing

```
- @sports.each do |sport|
  %tr
    %td= sport.name
    %td= sport.teams.count
```

and i suspect the sport.teams.count is what is causing the database to be queried over and over again. how do i fix this?

Comment: Do you use bullet? https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mischa said, you can use a counter_cache to solve your issue.  But you can also look at this sql statement to get the counts

```
@sports = Sport.select('sports.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teams WHERE teams.sport_id = sports.id) AS teams_count')
```

then you can just use `sport.teams_count`

```
- @sports.each do |sport|
  %tr
    %td= sport.name
    %td= sport.teams_count
```

Comment: could i use both this query and a country_cache?

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane: if you use `counter_cache`, you don't need this query. Only use it if you don't use the cache.

Comment: counter_cache will probably be an easier method to deploy across the models i think

Comment: i agree but i'd just like to let you know that this is another option. plus you can't use a counter cache if you want to get a count of 'active' teams, for example.

Comment: so counter cache cant filter out conditions?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [`counter_cache`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-counter_cache) for this. Also see this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column).